# Right demand = 正确的要求 in this situation?

Tags: word-choice, word

Suppose you and your teammates are negotiating with another company B.

Your teammates think your company needs to offer B $100M and ask B to do X.

But you think your company needs to offer B $100M and ask B to do Y, not X. **You think getting X is utterly useless for our company.**

What I am trying to say is, even if company agrees to do X, it will be useless to our company. So **X is completely useless for us**.

In this situation, you will say "We need to ask them to do what is necessary for us. That is, we need to **demand the right thing.**" or **demand something useful for us**.

What is the Chinese word to describe your argument? 正确的要求 (正確的要求) meaning "Right (correct) demand"? Or 有用的需求 meaning "Useful demand"?

If yes, can you shorten 正确的要求 or 有用的需求 into two-character noun word? 正求? 确要? 用求? This two-character word doesn't need to be an existing word in the dictionary. It's just a catch-phrase slogan. What would that be?

And 要求 is more appropriate than 需求, right? According to this [link](https://tw.hinative.com/questions/9325278), 需求 means to just need something, 要求 means to need someone else to do something. We are now asking the other company B to do something. So I guess 要求 is correct, and 需求 is not correct. Right?

Answer (score 1):

正确的要求 is correct but somewhat weird. 正求 and 确要 are not valid Chinese, making them up won't get your meaning across.

I would say 我们得让他们知道我们想要什么: We need to let them know what we want.

Short slogan: 使彼知吾愿。Pseudo Wenyan is always the go-to option if you really want it short, and not understandable by a lot of people.

Comment: If it's a long sentence, that's good. But my intention is to come up with a short slogan. Catchphrase type of thing.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the Chinese word to describe your argument? 正确的要求 (正確的要求)?
> "Right (correct) demand"?

The "Right (correct) demand" is more than "更合理的要求" or "更有利的要求"。 Because we can't say your teammate's thought is wrong, but just because your thought is better.

BTW, if you really wanna shorten 正确的要求 (正確的要求) into two-character, I would say it's "正解".

so " That is, we need to demand the right thing." can say "这样才是正解".

Comment: I edited my question to make it more clear what I want. What I am trying to say is, even if company agrees to do X, it will be useless to our company. Whether the company will agree to do X or not is not the point. So **X is completely useless for us**. So 有用的要求 is better?

Comment: in this case, if I were you. I would use '合理诉求' or '规求'  in short.

Answer (score 1):

正確的要求/決定是讓他作"Y", 因為我們不需要"X" - The correct request/decision is asking him to do "Y" because we don't need "X".

Answer (score 1):

Normally, 正當的要求 is a better phrase, but this is not what you are asking for. There's a number of ways to get your meaning across, it really depends on what you're trying to accomplish.

I don't think 有用的要求/需求 are good choices, as "useful demand" is not the same as "to demand something useful". They also sound awkward.

Althuogh you are correct regarding the difference between 要求 and 需求，in this case you can only 要求 the correct thing if you are very clear on what is useful to you, i.e., what your 需求 is. So, if you're trying to emphasize this aspect, you can say that you need to 明確需求 when communicating within your group. Or, if you are trying to say that you only have a limited amount of resources (for example, $100M) and they need to be spent wisely, you may say "(好鋼)用在刀刃上".